# Angular2.beta.14 with PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

Hello I was using angular2.beta.4 but when I tried to install PrimeNG, that requires angular2.beta.13, it didn't work. So, I installed angular.beta.14 but I still got the following errors:

```
The package angular2@2.0.0-beta.14 does not satisfy its siblings'       peerDependencies requirement
Peer primeng@1.0.0-beta.1 wants angular2@2.0.0-beta.13
```

Can't angular2.beta.14 run packages for previous versions ?

Comment: It should still work though if you run the app.

Answer (score 0):

i wouldnt recommend doing that, since beta.14 does contain some breaking changes, for e.x the Dependency Injection now requires the annotation .. `constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) ele : ElementRef){}` instead of `constructor(private ele : ElementRef){}`

AFAIK PrimeNg Works with angular beta 9 versions.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the breaking changes? I cannot find them at official changelog.